# Ambiguous call to function max in Cassandra database

Tags: cassandra

I'm updating from Cassandra 3.11 to 4.1, and running into the following issue. One of my queries is requesting a `MAX` of a clustering column. This was working fine in 3.11, but in 4.1 it gives me the following error:

`InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Ambiguous call to function max (can be matched by following signatures: system.max : (uuid) -> uuid, system.max : (timeuuid) -> timeuuid, system.max : (blob) -> blob): use type casts to disambiguate"`

I can replicate this with the following MWE:

`CREATE TABLE test (name text, testid timeuuid, primary key((name), testid)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (testid desc);`

Running a query like `SELECT MAX(testid) FROM test;` gives the error above. Is this a bug, or has something changed in how `MAX` works from 3.11?

Comment: I don't see any documentation regarding the change but try using maxtimeuuid instead.

Comment: @stevenlacerda that function seems to turn a timestamp into a timeuuid for comparison, not sure how that would help here.

Comment: You don't have a timestamp though, you have a timeuuid field.

Comment: @stevenlacerda from the docs, `maxTimeuuid` is used for things like `WHERE testid > maxTimeuuid('2023-05-05')`. That's not what I'm trying to do here. I want the largest timeuuid in the table, not all timeuuids larger than some fixed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, it seems like Cassandra 4.1 simply requires you to explicitly cast the value inside the `MAX`. So something like `SELECT MAX((timeuuid)testid) FROM test;` works. It also works to use one of the time conversion functions, e.g. `SELECT MAX(toTimestamp(testid)) FROM test;`. I'm not sure why Cassandra 4.1 can't figure out the type of `testid` from the table definition though.